# Issue in Redirection From Login Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

When the form is submitted, I run a GraphQL mutation. If it's successful, I want to redirect to a private page `/panel` after a token is returned and stored in local storage. If not, I want to show an error message from my `StatusMessage()`function.

The issue is that if login is unsuccessful, the error message works fine. But if the login is successful, I still get redirected to `/404`instead of `/panel`. However, when I go back to my `/login`page, I am automatically redirected to `/panel` this time. I don't know what goes wrong on the first time. Maybe the token is returned a few seconds late and redirection happens earlier?

Is there a solution to this? Here's my code:

```
function LoginPage (props: any){

  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);

  const [removeUser] = useMutation(LoginMutation);

 // useEffect(() => {
  // if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
  //     setShouldRedirect(true);
 // },[] );


   function submitForm(email: string, password: string) {
     setIsSubmitted(true);
       removeUser({
         variables: {
             email: email,
             password: password,
         },
     }).then(({ data }: any) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
       setShouldRedirect(true);
       //props.history.push("/panel");
     })
     .catch((error: { message: string; }) => {
       setShouldRedirect(false);
       console.log("Error msg:" + error.message);
       setErrorMessage(error.message);
     })
   }
   if(shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to="/panel" />;
     return (
           <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
             <CssBaseline />
             <div style={{
               display: 'flex',
               flexDirection: 'column',
               alignItems: 'center'
             }}>
               <Avatar>
                 <LockOutlinedIcon />
               </Avatar>
               <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                 Sign in
               </Typography>
               <Formik
                 initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                 onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                   setTimeout(() => {
                     alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                     actions.setSubmitting(false);
                   }, 1000);
                 }}
                 validationSchema={schema}
               >
                 {props => {
                   const {
                     values: { email, password },
                     errors,
                     touched,
                     handleChange,
                     isValid,
                     setFieldTouched
                   } = props;
                   const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                     e.persist();                
                     handleChange(e);
                     setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                   };
                   return (
                     <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                     onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                     submitForm(email, password);}}>
                       <TextField
                         variant="outlined"
                         margin="normal"
                         id="email"
                         fullWidth
                         name="email"
                         helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                         error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                         label="Email"     
                         value={email}
                         onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                       />
                       <TextField
                         variant="outlined"
                         margin="normal"
                         fullWidth
                         id="password"
                         name="password"
                         helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                         error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                         label="Password"
                         type="password"
                         value={password}
                         onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                       /> 
                       {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(shouldRedirect, errorMessage)}

                       <FormControlLabel
                         control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                         label="Remember me"
                       />
                       <br />
                       <Button className='button-center'
                         type="submit"
                         disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                       >                       
                         Submit</Button>
                       <br></br>
                       <Grid container>
                         <Grid item xs>
                           <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                             Forgot password?
                           </Link>               
                       </Grid>
                     </form>
                   )
                 }}
               </Formik>
             </div>
             {/* {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>} */}
           </Container>
     );
 }

 export default LoginPage;
```

Edit: This is how I am doing private routing:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

export const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
    const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
        isAuthenticated
            ? React.createElement(component, props)
            : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/404'}}/>
    );
    return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
  };

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component= {HomePage}></Route>
      <Route path='/login' component= {LoginPage}></Route>
      <PrivateRoute
      path='/panel'
      isAuthenticated={token}
      component={PanelHomePage}
      />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Stack Overflow. Why would you want to read from localStorage if you already have information that user is logged in in your react state? You are somewhat violating single source of truth principle with it

Comment: Hey, I am still learning! You're right. I should use ```shouldRedirect```and shouldn't check for local storage. I tried to remove the ```useEffect```but the issue is still the same. I also tried to put ```if(shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to="/panel" />;```inside the ```useEffect```but that too gives me typescript errors. Could you suggest an alternative? @MarioNikolaus

Comment: I added some more details to the qs @MarioNikolaus

Answer (score 1):

You are reading token only on script load. So once user logs in the app via login form, he is redirected to 404 because you are not rereading token from localstorage. Once you refresh page, you have token and therefore user gets login.

That however won't solve all your problems, because you are not rerendering app. You have to have `isLoggedIn` check somewhere in the app, to make sure you rerender component.

Comment: After ```then(({ data }: any)```, I am setting ```shouldRedirect()```to true, which should do the same job as ```isLoggedIn```because if something is being returned then it means that the login is successful. How can I use this to fix the problem then? Even if I make a separate ``ìsLoggedIn```state, I will still be setting it the same way where I am setting ```shouldRedirect```

Comment: Where exactly should I reread the token then? I already tried it in the ```useEffect```but the problem was still the same.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you refactor the source of the `token` variable to useState or a store that it will help you much achieve your goal much easier

Comment: Did you read what I write? From the reason why your app behaves like it does you should be able to rewrite your logic. Put isLoggedIn inside your App component, and then update it with callback once the user successfully fills in the form. You have to have that information inside App to provide your ProtectedRoute with necessary check for token. Currently your app component does not have details about token once it is set.

Comment: Perhaps create a provider to pass the token to child components or use a store and take advantage of async techniques